Vs code is not showing the suggestion and errors are not showing in flutter

I was working perfectly fine yesterday without any issues. However, when I started working today, I noticed that the errors that usually appear when the import of a class or object is not written properly or if there are any syntax errors are not showing up. Additionally, all the classes and objects are showing up in white text, whereas they used to appear in different colors.
The emulator options to select for running the project are not showing up in the bottom right corner. Previously, I had the opportunity to select a device and run the project.

I have reinstalled the VS Code, flutter SDK, VS Code flutter, and dart extension and restarted a couple of times, but didn't solve the problem.
Flutter doctor is working perfectly with no errors. I think the problem is in VS Code but didn't have any errors to work with.
Thanks in advance, hope you guys will help.


I tried finding a solution to my problem by looking up answers on Stack Overflow and Google, but none of the suggested solutions worked. Initially, I tried reinstalling the Flutter SDK, VS Code, and its extensions, but it didn't make a difference. However, when I uninstalled VS Code, cleared the cache, and reinstalled it, my issue was resolved.
LINK This link helps you.
